# How to find unique identifier of a list within a tuple?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples, uniqueidentifier

I have a tuple which looks as below:

```
x = (2, 3, 4, [34, 45, 89])
```

I can find `unique identifier` of `x` using `id(x)`

How can I find the unique identifier of the `list` object `[34, 45, 89]`?

Comment: What do you mean by `unique identifier`? `id`?

Comment: The list is the fourth element, so `id(x[3])`.

Comment: Thinking of `id()` as a "unique identifier" is kind of missing the point of this function.  It's only unique as long as the original object exists; as soon as all references to the object are gone, and it gets garbage-collected, the ID can (and often *will*) be reused - most commonly by the next created instance of the same type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `map` to map the `id` function (identifier function) for each value in the list:

```
>>> list(map(id, x))
[140725109860176, 140725109860208, 140725109860240, 1366170771648]
>>>
```

Or a list comprehension:

```
>>> [id(i) for i in x]
[140725109860176, 140725109860208, 140725109860240, 1366170771648]
>>>
```

Comment: thanks. I understand the second approach but can you explain little more about `IIUC try`?

Comment: @meallhour "If I understand correctly" :)